# Invalid json for Java type io.trino.server.TaskUpdateRequest

Tags: amazon-emr, trino

I'm getting the "Unrecognized token 'io': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')" ERROR when trying to do a simple CTAS in my Trino cluster with no underlying complexity.
I've tried restarting the cluster, increasing cluster size, but this silly error persists. Some days the error happens, and other days it doesn't. It's debilitating for our ETL work and I need to figure out what is causing it.

I'm running Trino 359 on EMR 6.4.0. Hive catalog using Glue.
error message:
Unexpected response from http://10.193.20.153:8889/v1/task/20211027_220021_01468_gtbqw.3.2?summarize com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'io': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false') at [Source: (byte[])"io.airlift.jaxrs.JsonMapperParsingException: Invalid json for Java type io.trino.server.TaskUpdateRequest

```html
create table ide.stage_5
    with (format = 'ORC')
    as (
        select distinct i.*
        from ide.stage_4 i
    );
```

Comment: Troubleshooting step: try "(format = Parquet)" to see if the issue is write format dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further discovery, this was being caused by the "distinct" -- it will be successful if run without the distinct.

The unsuccessful source table: This table is a Glue (hive) partitioned ORC table with SNAPPY compression, 500 columns, and 770,087 rows.

The query can be successfully run with "distinct" on a similar table with fewer columns: Glue (hive) partitioned ORC table with SNAPPY compression, 133 columns, and 756,287 rows.

Somewhere between 133 columns and 500 columns seems to be a bug, and I have submitted a ticket here: https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/9808